# M2 setup:upgrade takes for ever after Data migration

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration

Ran data migration into a default Magento 2.3.3 from Magento 1.14.4 and when ever I run `setup:upgrade` it takes >4 minutes in this step alone

```
Module 'Magento_Customer': 
Running data recurring...
```

Total Customers are 468k with 18 custom attributes inly two of them are select and that also uses M2 core Yes/No source.

Any insight will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite RecurringData like this

app/code/YourVendor/YourPackage/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Setup\RecurringData" type="YourVendor\YourPackage\Setup\RecurringData" />
```

app/code/YourVendor/YourPackage/Setup/RecurringData.php

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    // empty
}
```

And reindexer doesnot reindex but better add your own schedule to reindex customer_grid